# Authorization issues with django-wiki

Tags: django, django-wiki

I'm using django-wiki as a part of a larger user portal which is authenticated via Duo. I've already made the hooks for Django-wiki to redirect to the portal login page for authentication instead of using the inbuilt login mechanism. My question is two fold:

1. I only want a subset of authenticated portal users to be able to view the wiki. Everyone else should get a "You are not authorized to view this page" message when they try to access the wiki.
2. I want only a subset of authorized users of the wiki to have write privileges, everyone else should only have read privs.

How do I accomplish this? Thanks for your help!